# How to redirect to a 'page with class name inside form tag' inside web browser using vb.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to interact with the website using the web browser in vb.net(windows app). The web site has 10 pages. The application goes fine with three pages. But while directing to the fourth page, it says '500-Internal server error'. I am redirecting the pages using the 'NEXT' button click(used to redirect to next page),which is already there in the third page.

Differnce between third and fourth page form tags are below:

```
3 rd page: <form action="accessController.asp?page=8" method="post" name="myform">
4 th page: <form class="little" action="accessController.asp?page=12" method="post" name="myform">
```

I am used two different ways to redirect:

The below code is using the 'Next' image button click:

```
Dim objForm As HTMLFormElement

    objForm = htmObject.all.item("i_strFormName")
    Dim objimag As IHTMLElementCollection
    objimag = htmObject.images

    If Not objimag Is Nothing Then

        For Each htmlElement As IHTMLElement In objimag
            Dim imgUrl As String = htmlElement.getAttribute("Alt")
            If imgUrl = "Next" Then

                htmlElement.click()

            End If
        Next
    Else
        blnFound = True
        intErrorCode = 1
    End If
    objimag = Nothing
```

This is using the form submit:

```
 Dim objForm As HTMLFormElement

    objForm = htmObject.all.item(i_strFormName)
    If Not objForm Is Nothing Then
        blnCntrlFoundError = False

        If i_strAction <> "" Then
            objForm.action = i_strAction

        End If

        objForm.submit()
    Else
        blnFound = True
        intErrorCode = 1
    End If
    objForm = Nothing
```

Comment: where is your redirect code ??

Comment: Kindly check on the above code